# How to create a folder and files?

Tags: java

How do I create a Folder and a "n" number of files within the folder, and how do I rename the files inside the folder automatically using Java?

Eg. If "N" files are provided under a folder the names of the files must be changed automatically.

```
January(folder name)
01-01-2012.txt
""" """""".txt
"""""""""".txt
31-01-2012.txt
```

After implementation

```
January(folder Name)
01012012.txt
"""""""".txt
"""""""".txt
31012012.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to rename the files that matches a pattern to some other pattern?

Comment: You're asking far too much without showing any evidence of an attempt at all!

Comment: yes using java i need to change the files. yes exactly the files are follwing one pattern and it must be changed to the other.

Comment: Provide SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) so we could see what you have tried. Also, is this homework?

Comment: Since there is still not enough information, I flag this as unclear. No example, not enough detail.